# Returning a class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
class Wolf {
    var hunger = 10
    val food = "meat"

    fun eat() {
        println("The Wolf is eating $food")
    }
}

class MyWolf {
    var wolf: Wolf? = Wolf()

    fun myFunction() {
        wolf?.eat()
    }
}

fun getAlphaWolf(): Wolf? {
    return Wolf()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var w: Wolf? = Wolf()

    if (w != null) {
        w.eat()
    }

    var x = w?.hunger
    println("The value of x is $x")

    var y = w?.hunger ?: -1
    println("The value of y is $y")

    var myWolf = MyWolf()
    myWolf?.wolf?.hunger = 8
    println("The value of myWolf?.wolf?.hunger is ${myWolf?.wolf?.hunger}")

    var myArray = arrayOf("Hi", "Hello", null)
    for (item in myArray) {
        item?.let { println(it) }
    }

    getAlphaWolf()?.let { it.eat() }

    w = null
    var z = w!!.hunger
}
```

This above code is extracted from a Kotlin textbook.
I have problem with the following:

```
fun getAlphaWolf(): Wolf? {
     return Wolf()
}
```

As there is only a class called Wolf but no variable called Wolf in the code.
I wonder if it is possible to return a class inside a function?
What is the output if a class is returned inside a function?

Comment: While the other answers explain the syntax baffling you and give you a comparison to - hopefully - more familiar Java example, I would like to point out that a class cannot really be returned from a method/function as in the fact that class is a definition; a template; a set of parameters which are to be possessed and capabilities which are to be fulfilled. A single instance that fulfils the definition given in a class is what we call an object. So, the method `getAlphaWolf()` from the example returns `an object` of type `Wolf` i.e. an object implementing the class `Wolf`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with Java, then this Kotlin is equivalent to:

```java
public class Application {
    public Wolf getAlphaWolf() {
        return new Wolf();
    }
}
```

So, in Kotlin you are calling the no-arguments constructor. If you want to return the class `Wolf`, then that is also possible:

```
fun getWolfClass(): KClass<Wolf> {
    return Wolf::class
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following code, the primary constructor of class `Wolf` is called:

```
fun getAlphaWolf(): Wolf? {
     return Wolf()
}
```

So, getAlphaWolf returns a completely new instance of `Wolf` with default values: `Wolf(hunger=10,food=meat)`.

Update: by the way, making the return type of this function nullable is redundant, because a new instance cannot be `null`.